# Json unmarshal fails due to invalid characters

Tags: json, xml, go

Im having difficulties to unmarshal json content in golang.
One of the fields in my object contains xml content and occasionally it will fail, claiming messages such as: `invalid character '\x..' in string literal`

I understand that this is as a result of control characters in my xml, but dont know how to handle it.
I store my documents in mongoosejs and save the xml field as type String
My struct Im trying to deserialize to is declared this way:

```
type A struct {
  Xml []byte `json:"xml"`
}
```

Unmarshaling is done the following way:

```
var xml A
err := json.Unmarshal(content, &xml)
```

Comment: Can you post an example JSON containing such XML which cannot be unmarshalled? And also example code how you try to unmarshal it?

Comment: @icza I cant, this is a very long xml (~2MB) and I honestly dont know where the error in the file is.

Comment: @buddy123 Keep chopping the file in half and check which half gives you the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JSON cannot contain any control characters, I found the most convenient solution to simply convert the xml data to base64, e.g:

```
// before sending in javascript
a.xml = new Buffer(a.xml).toString('base64')
```

Then, In golang side:

```
// Declare a new type for custom unmarshaling
type XmlB64 []byte
func (b *XmlB64) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    if b == nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("UnmarshalJSON on nil pointer")
    }

    if len(data) == 0 {
        return nil
    }

    if x, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(string(data)); err != nil {
        return err
    } else {
        *b = x
    }

    return nil
}
```

After doing that, Unmarshalling base64 content is done without doing anything special in the code. We first change our struct:

```
type A struct {
  Xml XmlB64 `json:"xml"`
}
```

Unmarshal:

```
var xml A
err := json.Unmarshal(content, &xml)
```

Comment: The encoding/json package uses base64 encoding for []byte values.  There's no need for the XmlB64 type.